# How do I clone or duplicate a post with the WordPress Command Line Interface WP-CLI?

Tags: wp-cli

I know that I can clone or duplicate a post with several plugins. The one I use most often is https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicate-post/. However I am using the WP-CLI more and more lately and I would like to be able to duplicate or clone a post from the command line.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Copy a post is pretty simple, but copy the post meta can be a pita. I have created this gist https://gist.github.com/alejandrogih/fc79e22dd7d9c65048689a4bc12e0dce Hope it helps to someone else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloning a post via wp-cli is little trickier. It needs two steps:

1. Create a file where save the information of post. Suppose, following command create a file named file.txt from hello post (id 1). In this case file.txt which save on root directory.

   `wp post get 1 > file.txt`
2. Create new post from this file. In our scenario file.txt saved all information of `hello` post. Following command create a post named `duplicate`

   `wp post create ./file.txt --post_title="duplicate"`

Comment: You got me on the right track thanks. Here is what I finally came up with `wp post get 6815 --field=content | wp post create - --post_title="Duplicate Of Some Title" --post_status='publish'` The "-" after `wp post create` says read the content from the standard input. The `--field=content` limits info to just the content field.

Answer (score 30):

This can now be done via WP-CLI using `$ wp post create --from-post=1`. It even dupes the meta data.

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer

Comment: @catgofire agreed

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for your answer and @Mrinal and confirming it would work with a pipe @tfrangio.

I was interested too in copying the meta values from one post to the other, so after creating the post with the duplicate with the pipe:

```
wp post get 6815 --field=content | wp post create - --post_title="Title of dup" --post_status='draft'
```

After I get the ID of the new post, I passed the meta_keys which I was interested...

assuming `14` is the source post_ID and `21` the target post_ID, I want to copy `tie_hide_related` and `tie_sidebar_pos`:

```
for meta_key in tie_hide_related tie_sidebar_pos ; \
do wp post meta get 14 $meta_key | \
xargs wp post meta update 21 $meta_key \
; done
```

`xargs` is needed to pass the value returned by post-meta-get to wp post-meta update, even if [the documentation says it reads from stdin](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/meta/update/), without xargs some single values are read as an one item list, thus changing the behaviour of the value

Then, to copy the terms of a taxonomy, let's say `category`:

```
 for cat_id in `wp post term list 14 category --format=ids` ; \
 do wp post term add 21 category $cat_id --by=id ; done
```

This last step could be repeated for several taxonomies.